# Открытие каталога программно с помощью php или javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Доброго времени суток, соратники!

Прошу прощение, если вопрос кривой. Возможна ли реализация на php или javascript открытия каталога с помощью нужной программы. Не принципиально программа должна находится на сервере или на клиентском ПК, оба варианта подходят.
Например, на сервере есть папка со снимками, ее нужно открыть в программе для просмотра снимков, именно ВСЮ папку. Расскажите пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать. СПАСИБО.

Comment: Если программа просмотра снимков принимает консольные аргументы, то что-то вроде `system("gpicview /home/user");` в PHP не подойдёт? Если нет, напишите подробнее, что нужно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Постараюсь развернуто объяснить.
Идея такова. На сервер (ubuntu server) пользователь загружает папку со снимками. Другим пользователям нужно их просмотреть (снимки медицинские). В теории хочется, чтоб каталог не скачивали, а открывали на web-странице.

Comment: То, с чего я начал. Отобразил содержимое каталога

if($handle=opendir('./')):
  while(false!==($file=readdir($handle))):
    //убираем лишние элементы
    if ($file!="." && $file!=".."):
echo"<a href=$file>$file</a>"; echo '<br>';
    endif;  
  endwhile;
  closedir($handle);  
endif;
?>

Comment: И в чём проблема — вы не знаете, как вывести изображение с помощью HTML? `<img src='$file'/>`.

Comment: дело в том, что снимки находящиеся в каталоге нужно открывать вместе. То есть весь каталог сразу в программе для просмотра снимков DICOM. В каталоге может быть от 100 до 800 снимков

Comment: На папку в сервере вам необходимо настроить ftp доступ и синхронизацию на локальной машине, либо заюзать vns или какой нибудь rdp для этого, с выводом в браузер. Или примонтировать удалёную папку как диск к локальной машине.

Comment: Это запасной вариант. Таблица с пациентами будет расширяться. Я связал по id таблицу таблицу пациентов, с таблицей где хранятся ссылки на папки со снимками. Хотелось чтоб это выглядело как будто я на обычный jpg нажимаю и операционка спрашивает с помощью чего я хочу открыть файл, тоже очень хочется реализовать на папку

Comment: Если хотите отобразить сразу все снимки, тогда лучше делать периодически их миниатюры. Отображать мелкие, а уже при клике показывать оригинал. Если снимков будет очень много и хорошего качества, то сервер и сеть могут не выдержать. Можете сделать как будто прокрутка вниз (смотреть еще фото), а сами через ajax получать новую партию. Все 800+ не влезут в экран.